# How to remove the space between navbar toggle menu collapse and header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, menu, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap v4.0 for my site, and I have made a basic navbar which goes like [this](https://codepen.io/pouyavey/pen/bvjZzJ)

(Codepen link).

And the problem with this menu is that, when you minimize the page to see how this nav works in md and sm devices, it shows a space between the navbar and the header:

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5f3D.png)

So my question is, how to remove this space?

Here is the html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom BKoodakBold">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img id="img1" class="hidden-xs" src="img/letter-logo.png" width="100" height="100"></img><script>rotateAnimation("img1",30);</script><img id="img2" src="img/text-logo.png" width="300" height="100"></img></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbarMd">
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg py-1 text-white"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbarMd">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        فروشگاه
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ویژه</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">پایین ترین قیمت ها</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">مرور کردن</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ساخت سلاح</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">پوشاک</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">تجارت</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        راهنما
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">پرسش و پاسخ</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        جامعه
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">وبلاگ</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">کاتالوگ</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">درباره</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">لیست قیمت</a>
                        <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">API Documentation</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">npm package</a> -->
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">مالی</a>
                </li> 
                <button class="btn BJadidBold">ورود/ عضویت</button>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I have searched the forum to find a related problem, but I couldn't find anything useful. So it would be best if you can help me with that..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @Anuresh No, not yet!

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space is the overflow of `.navbar-custom`.

You have to change the `height:100px;` to `auto` in media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-custom {
      height:auto;
    }
}
```

> Note:Place media query to bottom of your normal css. In codepen its on
>   top.